# Conditional Expected Value of the Maximum of a Random Sample

Tags: integration, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I have the following expression which comes from *Aaberge, R. (2000). Characterizations of Lorenz curves and income distributions. Social Choice and Welfare, 17(4), 639-653*. This denotes the income gap ($g_k(x)$) between a unit with income $x$ and the expected maximum income of a random sample of size $k+1$ with incomes lower than $x$:
$$g_k(x)=x-E\big(\max_{i\leq k+1}X_i|X_i\leq x,i=1,2,...,k+1\big)\quad (1)$$
where $X_1,X_2,...X_{k+1}$ is a random sample of size $k+1$ drawn from $F$, which denotes the cumulative distribution function of an income variable $X$. **I need to arrive to the following expression:**

$$E_{g_{k}}(X)=\int_0^1F^{-1}(t)dt-\int_0^1\frac{1}{u^{k+1}}\int_0^uF^{-1}(t)dt^{k+1}du \quad (2)$$

Starting from the latter I was able to arrive to:
$$E_{g_{k}}(X)=\int_0^1F^{-1}(F(x))f(x)dx-\int_0^1\frac{1}{u^{k+1}}\int_0^uy(k+1)F(y)^kf(y)dydu\quad (3)$$

and with the help of https://jamesmccammon.com/2017/02/18/finding-the-expected-value-of-the-maximum-of-n-random-variables/, I believe I can write this as:

$$E_{g_{k}}(X)=\int_0^1xf(x)dx-\int_0^1\frac{1}{u^{k+1}}\int_0^uyf_Y(y)dydu \quad (4)$$

where $f_Y(y)$ denotes the probability density function of the variable $Y=max(X_1,X_2,...,X_{k+1})$.

I am really doubtful with the second term of expression $(1)$. I just can't figure out how to arrive to the second term that appears in expression $(2)$. I also checked this post [Conditional expectation of X given X is greater than Y](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169833/conditional-expectation-of-x-given-x-is-greater-than-y) to review conditional expectations, but I'm still uncertain. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked directly with Rolf Aaberge, and he sent me the following notes which I believe solve my question:

[Expected_Max_Notes_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep88i.jpg)

[Expected_Max_Notes_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QkML.jpg)